# Discord.js | Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a  discord bot for a friend and everything worked until i tried to make an unban command. when i tried to unban someone it did not work. then i looked at the error. it displayed:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined
at C:\Users\user\folder_name\commands\unban.js:37:67
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined
at C:\Users\user\folder_name\commands\unban.js:37:67
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

this is my code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'unban',
    description: 'unban user',
    aliases: [],
    cooldown: 0,
    args: true,
    usage: '<mention> [reason]',
    guildOnly: true,
    execute(message, args, client) {
        console.log(message.content);
        const embedMsg = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#0000ff')
            .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
            .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('botname', client.user.displayAvatarURL);

        let member = message.mentions.members.first();

        if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
            embedMsg.setDescription(`You don't have permission to unban!`);
            return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
        }

        if (!args.length >= 1) {
            embedMsg.setDescription('^unban takes at least one argument! the proper usage is ^unban <mention> [reason]');
            message.channel.send(embedMsg);
        }

        if (args.length < 2) {
            message.guild.unban(member).then(() => {
                embedMsg.setDescription(`${member.displayName} has been succesfully unbanned`);
                return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
            }).catch((err) => {
                embedMsg.setDescription(`Could not unban ${member.displayName}`);
                console.log(err);
                return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
            });
            return;
        }

        newargs = "";
        for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            newargs += (args[i] + " ");
        }

        message.guild.unban(member).then(() => {
            embedMsg.setDescription(`${member.displayName} has been succesfully unbanned for reason ${newargs}`);
            return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
        }).catch((err) => {
            embedMsg.setDescription(`Could not unban ${member.displayName}`);
            console.log(err);
            return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
        });
        return;
    }
}
```

does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says in the discord.js's official docs that the unban method returns a member object https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=unban

The reason why it says 'undefined' is because the member object you are trying to access is not in the server/guild. So, therefore you need add a reference to the member object that the method returns:

```
message.guild.unban('some user ID').then((member) => {
   embedMsg.setDescription(`${member.username} has been succesfully unbanned for reason ${newargs}`);
            return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Unbun](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=unban) method return a [user](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) promise, so user dont have property `displayName`, you need use `.username`

And you can use `user.id` for unban, so right way will be `let member = message.mentions.members.first() || args[0]`

This check doing wrong, because its not stop code execute

```js
if (!args.length < 2) {
    embedMsg.setDescription('^unban takes at least one argument! the proper usage is ^unban <mention> [reason]');
    return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
}
```

Amm and whats this part code doing? Why its duplicate?

```js
if (args.length < 2) {
    message.guild.unban(member)
        .then(() => {
            embedMsg.setDescription(`${member.username} has been succesfully unbanned`);
            return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            embedMsg.setDescription(`Could not unban ${member.username}`);
            console.log(err);
            return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
        });
    return;
}
```

**The edited code**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'unban',
    description: 'unban user',
    aliases: [],
    cooldown: 0,
    args: true,
    usage: '<mention> [reason]',
    guildOnly: true,
    execute(message, args, client) {
        const embedMsg = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#0000ff')
            .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.displayAvatarURL)
            .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter('botname', client.user.displayAvatarURL);
        let member = message.mentions.members.first() || args[0]
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) {
            embedMsg.setDescription(`You don't have permission to unban!`);
            return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
        }
        if (!args.length < 2) {
            embedMsg.setDescription('^unban takes at least one argument! the proper usage is ^unban <mention> [reason]');
            return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
        }
        let newargs = args.splice(1,args.length).join(' ')

        message.guild.unban(member)
            .then(() => {
                embedMsg.setDescription(`${member.username} has been succesfully unbanned for reason ${newargs}`);
                return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                embedMsg.setDescription(`Could not unban ${member.username}`);
                console.log(err);
                return message.channel.send(embedMsg);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
user_id: Value "<@!666777521999708170>" is not snowflake.
at C:\Users\user\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15
at C:\Users\user\bot\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
name: 'DiscordAPIError',
message: 'Invalid Form Body\n' +
'user_id: Value "<@!666777521999708170>" is not snowflake.',
path: '/api/v7/guilds/666571326634459137/bans/%3C@!666777521999708170%3E',
code: 50035,
method: 'DELETE'
 }

Comment: and in discord: could not ban undefined